# Manugistics/Avyx Forest and Trees scheduling utilities

Tags: scheduling, legacy, rad

In 1994, someone wrote a scheduling package for NASA utilizing a scheduling package of software that defined forests and trees.  I have the complete source of the package except for the one library.  No where in the include files is there any indication of who wrote it, but I have reason to believe that it was Manugistics.  Can anybody provide any insight?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question about Forest & Trees [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71682/does-anyone-remember-forest-trees).

The best answer I got was from [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490014/james), who gave me this email address:  sales@msmcomputers.co.uk.

I have since emailed them, and they are very helpful.

If you need any help with F&T itself, or with developing your F&T app, my email is in my profile.  :)